# Android getting Mac Address

Tags: android, macos, mac-address

I want to write an application which give the user the mac address of the device. How to do that ? wifiInf.getMacAddress(); method not worked for me. is there any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Were you connected to wifi? check that first.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html

Comment: i checked the android developer many before but i could not find the answer. I am using 2.2 froyo; i am connected to internet through wifi; but still WifiInfo.getMacAddress(); is not working. I give the force close error. Any other idea?

Comment: code? a little difficult to try and know what is going on with no code.

Comment: do you have the permission set for WiFi access in the manifest? If not, that would cause the crash